# PyTorch - Correctly Computing Neural Tangent Kernel (Jacobian per data point)

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, automatic-differentiation

In PyTorch, I have a fixed dataset `x` of shape `(batch size, input dimension)` and a feedforward network `network`. If I call the output of the network `yhat = network(x)` of shape `(batch size, output dimension)`, how do I compute the gradient of `yhat` with respect to `network`'s parameters for each data point individually?

Answer (score 0):

You could do `yhat.backward()` this will set `.grad` attribute for each network parameter and then you can read `.grad` as :

```
grads = [] 
for param in network.parameters():
     grads.append(param.grad)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It averages gradients over the batch dimension of `yhat`.

Comment: You will have to iterate over yhats too then!